# My application is not binding correctly for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to finish up this application using Angular but something is just not working as it should.

I have this controller:

```
app.controller('GetStartedCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$location', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $location) {

    var data = $location.search();
    $location.search({});

    $scope.years = [];
    $scope.months = [
        {value: '01', name: 'January'},
        {value: '02', name: 'February'},
        {value: '03', name: 'March'},
        {value: '04', name: 'April'},
        {value: '05', name: 'May'},
        {value: '06', name: 'June'},
        {value: '07', name: 'July'},
        {value: '08', name: 'August'},
        {value: '09', name: 'September'},
        {value: '10', name: 'October'},
        {value: '11', name: 'November'},
        {value: '12', name: 'December'}
    ];
    $scope.currentQuestion = 1;
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.form.zipcode = 12345;

}]);
```

And then I have this HTML in the template:

```
<div class="questionnaire">
    <form name="questionnaire" id="questionnaire" novalidate="true" ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <div class="question1 question" ng-class="{ 'overlay': currentQuestion > 1 }" ng-show="currentQuestion >= 1">
            <p>Saving money doesn't have to be work. Let's keep it simple.</p>
            <span>Enter Your Zip</span><input type="text" name="zipcode" ng-model="form.zipcode" required="true" ng-pattern="/^\d{{5}}(-\d{{4}})?$/" />
        </div>
        <div class="question2 question" ng-class="{ 'overlay': currentQuestion > 2 }" ng-show="currentQuestion >= 2">
            <p>Ok. You're located in {{city}}, {{state}}. We hope you're experiencing good weather there.</p>
            <span>Are You:</span><i>(check one)</i><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="business" value="business" /><label for="business" ng-model="form.type"><span></span>Business</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="residential" value="residential" /><label for="residential" ng-model="form.type"><span></span>Residential</label>
        </div>
        <pre>{{form}}</pre>
    </form>
</div>
```

So what is happening is I am setting the `$scope.form.zipcode` property to `12345` and it is correctly applying to the input field but not to the form property that is getting dumped at the bottom of the page:

[image: Zip Code box displaying correctly]

The strange thing is if I change the binding on the zipcode input to be something different, the dump at the bottom displays correctly but the zipcode box does not get filled in:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening and how I can fix it so the binding is being set up correctly?  Basically what needs to happen is that both the zipcode box should be filled in and the dump at the bottom should have the correct zipcode property.

If there is anything I need to clarify, please let me know.

Thanks!
Brandon

Comment: Bottom means the `{}` object that is being displayed in the images.

Comment: is this with only zipcode field or all field?

Comment: No, it is happening with every field, I just didn't want to spam the question with every field in the code, I have no idea what is going on with it.  I have another form that is setup very similarly that works fine.

Comment: if removing ng-pattern makes it work thn i can tell further

Comment: I take that back, it is only with the zipcode... I realized I made a stupid mistake and put the `ng-model` on the label for the checkboxes, so those are working correctly now.

Comment: Now how did you know that removing the `ng-pattern` would work :(

Comment: is it working without ng-pattern?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75147/discussion-between-brandon-shega-and-a-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think problem is with the `ng-pattern` not being matched,and it isnt allowing your value to get into the object.

Remove extra curly braces as mentioned by @ Matthew Green

finally

change your regex ng-pattern from

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{{5}}(-\d{{4}})?$/"
```

to

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/"
```

or dont use surrounding double quotes

```
 ng-pattern=/^\d{5}(-\d{{4}})?$/
```

Comment: The `ng-pattern` is definitely the issue here, but this still didn't solve it.

Comment: It's the extra curly braces not the double quotes. Remove those.

Comment: Ya, I didn't realize I pulled this input from an XSLT file and had to escape the curly braces originally. Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic a little but why does `ng-pattern` not require `""` like a normal attribute?

Comment: @BrandonShega may b it wouldnt work, but sinse its regex it cuases problem as i remeber an case it did

Comment: Ah okay, cool, thanks so much for your help and to @MatthewGreen as well.